# Graylog2 Stream filter rule

Tags: regex, logging, graylog

I've got a graylog server setup and working. (version 0.9.6, with web interface). I have a stream for log entries with severity NOTICE or higher.
I want to add a filter rule to that stream which filters out all the entries with the word nagios in them (also nagios: or nagios-plugins).

I've tried adding these rules to the stream (as a full message filter):

```
NOT .*nagios.*
-nagios\:*
 -*nagios*
NOT *nagios*
```

Result of those was that the stream stopped getting log entries.

How do I add a correct filter?

Answer (score 3):

Well, thanks to http://rubular.com and some testing this regexp works:

```
^((?!nagios).)*$
```

Answer (score 1):

Just `.*nagios.*` should be enough.